# AWS X-Ray not working in Edge Lambda and Authorizer lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I tried enabling AWS X-Ray in Lambda@Edge, Origin Response handler

I see that X-Ray does not trace it.

Can someone tell me if that will work?

Let me know if someone faced the same and what are the workarounds.

Edit: Interesting read https://kevinhakanson.com/2020-01-20-using-aws-x-ray-with-lambdaedge

Comment: What is the issue that you are experiencing? We natively support AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda as is, so it'd be interesting to know how we can help you solve the problem you are having.

Are you experiencing no traces being generated at all?

Comment: @ChanChiemJefferySaeteurn Thank you here is my problem

 I am not able to see the call from Gateway to Authorizer in X-Ray
&
I have a Lambda in Origin Response which is also not being shown as Invoked in the Flow

Comment: @Purna Are you saying the Lambda functions are failing and you are not seeing their traces because they failed? Or are the functions succeeding and you're just not seeing their traces? Also to be sure, you have authored the Lambda functions for the API Gateway authorizer and the response handler, and have checked the "active tracing" boxes in the Lambda console for both such functions, right?

Comment: I mean to say X Ray does not show the Lambdas executed at CloudFront Origin response

Answer (score 2):

Lambda@Edge does not support X-Ray, per the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-requirements-lambda-function-configuration

Comment: interestingly it works in origin request but does not work in origin response

Comment: That certainly is interesting.  Are you using an X-Ray daemon?

Comment: Also.. my Lambda@Edge is invoking a "classic" Lambda function that has X-Ray enabled.. and even the "classic" Lambda function doesn't appears in X-Ray..